# epoll_wait() syscall is blocked infinite ever after deregistering socket from epoll interesting list, shutting down socket, closing socket

Tags: c++, sockets, epoll

I have client and server applications and I use epoll for read and write. When any problem happened in server side, the server side shuts down and closes the socket descriptor. In client side the thread that tries to read from server gets end of stream notification and shuts down and closes the socket descriptor. In the thread that tries to write data to the server **epoll_wait()** syscall does not get socket error notification and is blocked infinite. What is the problem?

Comment: Hard to say, without seeing the code. Most likely, you consumed all events already, and you will never get a new event. Maybe this peice of example code (a Reactor implementation) can give you some hints: https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/SmlParser/blob/master/source/reactor.cpp

Comment: _socket error notification_ - what error would that be? Do you use edge or level triggered epoll?

Comment: _socket error notification_ - I mean EPOLLHUP or EPOLLERR. I use level triggered epoll.